# How to enable Sqlite on a Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, sqlite

I upgraded my Mac with OS X Mavericks last week.  It appears to have taken away support for Sqlite -- not Sqlite3, but sqlite.  I need that for a website I work on.  I went to Sqlite's website, but all I could find was older versions of Sqlite3.  Where can I find a version of Sqlite?  I've been through the `php.ini` and can only find one reference to `sqlite`.  In short, how do I get Sqlite support on my Mac?  I have Sqlite3 enabled and the issue isn't going away.

I uncommented `pdo_sqlite` in the `php.ini` and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, this was only an issue because I was using Zend Framework 1.12 and Apple upgraded to PHP 5.4 and 5.4, which in turn dropped some Sqlite support in favor of Sqlite 3.  Here are instructions on how to upgrade Zend to Sqlite 3 support.

https://github.com/gencer/zend-cache-sqlite3

Answer (score 1):

First, install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Then:

```
$ brew update && brew install sqlite
```

Comment: I get this warning.  Warning: sqlite-3.8.0.2 already installed